# Single writer, multiple reader character stream in C++ (equivalent to lisp make-broadcast-stream)

Tags: c++, boost, std

I'm trying to implement a process wide "event stream" that has the following properties:

- simple char stream
- one writer can post to it
- many readers will read from it (at their leisure)
- readers can "subscribe" and "unsubscribe" to the stream (with the implication that they will only ever see data from between those two events)

I am using Boost::asio so threading isn't actually an issue, all of this can/will be happening on the same thread.

The main point that's tricky is that when a string is written to the stream, I want all readers to read the entirety of the stream (not just what they happened to grab up).

Diagram could be like so:

```
W1 writes    "ABCD"
   R1 reads  "ABCD"
W1 writes    "EFGH"
   R2 reads  "ABCDEFGH"
W1 write     "."
   R1 reads  "EFGH."
   R2 reads  "."
```

Common Lisp has this exact idiom in #'make-broadcast-stream. I'm trying not to reinvent the wheel and have been looking into boost::iostreams but I'm not sure that's exactly what I need.

Any ideas on:

1. what the name of the idiom I'm trying to achieve is
2. any std:: or boost:: implementations of it

?